# Arcpy reclassify with function

Tags: arcpy, ndvi, reclassify, function, map-algebra

I have two rasters, one with NDVI values, and one with greyscale values (=(red band + green band + blue band) / 3).
The rasters have the same name.

I need to reclassify them in arcpy with the following formular:

```
if ndvivaluefrompixel >=-0.000005*greyscalepixelvalue+0.314367:
     return 2

if ndvivaluefrompixel <=-0.000005*greyscalepixelvalue+0.314367:
     return 1
```

I thought about using map algebra in arcpy but I'm not sure if it is possible to use such a function for reclassification?

Is this possible using map algebra/reclassify in arcpy? Of course this has to run in a loop then, so I have to use python.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

This is how I would do it (it requires the Spatial Analyst extension which I think you have):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension = "Spatial"

ndvi_raster = Raster("ndvivaluefrompixel")
grey_raster = Raster("grayscalepixelvalue")

output_raster = Con(ndvi_raster >= -0.000005 * grey_raster + 0.314367, 2, 1)
output_raster.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/outcon")
```